# Jersey Moxy based rest service not consuming nested json post request payload

Tags: java, json, rest, moxy

I have snake case representation of the json data *'{"first_name":"Michael", "last_name":"Jordan", "address_loc":{"city_name":"Mumbai", "street":"galino1"}}'*. I want to consume this data by jersey + moxy based post method resource in form of pojo representation. Please suggest.Please also note that normal camel case representation of json is working using given following code snippet but I have the requirement of using snake case.

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class Person {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

private AddressLoc addressLoc = new AddressLoc();

public Person(){};

public Address getAddressLoc() {
    return addressLoc ;
}
public void setAddressLoc(Address address) {
    this.addressLoc = address;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

}
```

Child/nested class

```
public class AddressLoc {

private String cityName;
private String street;

public AddressLoc(){};

public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
}
public void setCityName(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

}
```

Resource Class

```
   import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
   import javax.ws.rs.POST;
   import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
   import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
   import com.nabisoft.tutorials.jerseymoxy.model.Person;

@Path("/person")
public class PersonResource {

@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Path("/post")
public String postPerson(Person pers) throws Exception{

    System.out.println("First Name = "+pers.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name  = "+pers.getLastName());
    System.out.println("Last Name  = "+pers.getAddress().getCity());
    System.out.println("Last Name  = "+pers.getAddress().getStreet());

    return "ok";
}
}
```

Client code

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var ctxPath = "<%=request.getContextPath() %>";
        $(function(){                
            $("#postPerson, #postMessage").on("click", function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr("id") === "postMessage" ? ctxPath+"/service/message/post" : ctxPath+"/service/personwa/post",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: '{"first_name":"Michael", "last_name":"Jordan", "address_loc":{"city_name":"Mumbai", "street":"galino1"}}',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            });                
        });
    </script>
```

Apart from above listed codebase I also have "ApplicationConfig.java" and "JsonMoxyConfigurationContextResolver.java" without any fancy implementaion in it. Thanks.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

You want to add **javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement** annotation and provide another (snake case) name.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {

   @XmlElement(name="first_name")
   private String firstName;
```